# How to Encode a bigger JSON dataset to avro?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I'm learning to serialize data with avro. I would like to serialize a bigger dataset. Can someone help me how to iterate over a bigger dataset wihtout
hard coding a GenericRecordbuilder?

I would like just to read a Json File and add all data in a Record
then I would like to Encode the Json Data.

```
// built a schema

 val schema = SchemaBuilder
  .record("test")
  .fields
  .name("name").`type`().stringType().noDefault()
  .name("ID").`type`().intType().noDefault()
  .endRecord()

//how the schema looks like: {"type":"record","name":"test","fields": [{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"ID","type":"int"}]}
```

here I used to build a GenericRecordBuilder object:

```
 val obj = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema)
  .set("name", "anna")
  .set("ID", 2)
  .build
```

Here I would like to load a avro file 
for example:

```
val jsonDatei = spark.sqlContext.read.json("/home/learnAvro/data.json") // type: dataframe
```

And then I would like to encode the Json(not just a single record, all records) but I dont know how. I have following "framework":

```
val writer = new GenericDatumWriter[GenericRecord](schema)
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val jsonEncoder = EncoderFactory.get.jsonEncoder(schema, baos)

writer.write(obj, jsonEncoder)
jsonEncoder.flush()
```

the json data looks like this:

```
 {"name": "anna", "ID": 2}
 {"name": "frank", "ID": 5}
 {"name": "anton", "ID": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsonDatei.write.format("avro").save("jsonDatei.avro")`.

Additional details: https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/30/apache-avro-as-a-built-in-data-source-in-apache-spark-2-4.html

Comment: This does not work for me, because I'm not using spark 2.4

Comment: @Nika You can use this down to Spark 1.2 https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-4.0/README-for-old-spark-versions.md